# Programmatically add cards to Ankiweb on a mobile App

Tags: flutter, mobile, anki

I want to build an mobile app that should be able to add Flashcards to Ankiweb, so that those flashcards can be learnt in the Anki App.

I know that Anki has no official Rest API, but I was wondering how Ankidroid is managing to sync their cards to Ankiweb, as Ankidroid is also not completetly official. Has anybody tried to replicate their anki-syncing-feature or another approach for the api-problem?

#### Why my app needs this feature and why exporting Anki Cards is not a great option:

The App should give dictionary definitions/translations of unknown words. Those unkown words should be added to Anki to not forget them. Examplary user flow: You read a book/article and come across the word "cat" which you don't know. In the App you can enter the word cat and get the definition "a small animal with fur, four legs, a tail, and claws, usually kept as a pet or for catching mice". With a button you can add "cat" with its respective defintion to anki.
This would be the most desirable user flow. The app should be open source and free.